# AWS Signed URL issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I try to send request to AWS with signature using AWS Signature v4 Implementation for Web Browsers.

My request look like:
GET /test?id=ID-12

I get the 403 error with message like:

```
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.

The Canonical String for this request should have been
'GET
/test

accept:*/*
...
```

so, as you see, here no param, which I think the issue, but what I don't understand, how AWS can make a suggestion about what should have been? I mean signature is represent by hash, no? Or I'm missing something? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which service are you sending this to?  Can you show the complete error?  If it's XML, right-click and view source to get the correct formatting without interpretation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplifying the process a bit, AWS uses [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) to generate the signature.

One of the key principles is that HMAC does not encrypt the message. The message must be sent alongside the HMAC hash.  The receiving side will calculate the HMAC again and verify the results.

AWS explicitly talks a bit about this in the [Signature Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html):

> When an AWS service receives the request, it performs the same steps that you did to calculate the signature you sent in your request. AWS then compares its calculated signature to the one you sent with the request. If the signatures match, the request is processed. If the signatures don't match, the request is denied.

To answer your explicit question:  The string they're showing you that they used to generate the "Canonical String" is derived from the HTTP request itself.  The HTTP type as "GET" in the first line, the path passed to GET on the second line, and so on.

In other words, they're expecting the caller to understand what the request will look like, generate the Canonical String themselves beforehand, run their signature algorithm on it and the shared secret of the Access Key's Secret, and include the resulting hash in the request.  Then on their side they take elements from the HTTP request, run this process again, and verify the result is correct.

For your failure, if you post how you're generating the presigned URL, we might be able to diagnose where the failure is.